# How to use OpenGL in QT Creator

Tags: qt, opengl

I am working on OpenGL to create a GUI .I want to create some tabs which will help me to display different things in different windows. How is this possible using OpenGL? I read in some articles that we can use QT for that. Since I have already developed some of the GUI part in OpenGL using GLUT library ,is it possible to use the same code in QT? If so brief me how to make settings for OpenGL libraries in QT creator.

In my GUI I am trying to create a Car which is following a track.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be mixing some things up: OpenGL is a API with which you can instruct drivers to draw visual primitives, like lines, boxes, 3D triangles, pictures from buffer onto a render plane.

GLUT is a library that gives you a minimal environment around that, ie. it handles creating a window etc.

Neither of them are high-level UI description tools. Qt is really most likely what you want, as it will not only give you things like tab widgets etc, but also a feature-rich framework to do things like defining what should happen when you click a button, close a window etc.

There's a lot of examples of OpenGL usage within Qt widgets. In fact, a lot of visualization frontends use Qt and OpenGL. Qt has [extensive documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/painting-3d.html) on how to generate OpenGL contextes and draw inside Qt applications.